# if $(m,n)=1$ is this true that $(2^m-1,2^n-1)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $(m,n)=1$ is this true that $(2^m-1,2^n-1)=1$ ?

Observing $2^i-1$'s shows that it seems true! But how to prove it?

$2 \rightarrow 3$

$3 \rightarrow 7$

$4 \rightarrow 15$

$5 \rightarrow 31$

$6 \rightarrow 63$

Comment: Yes it is true, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the contrary:
Let $n$ be the smallest natural number for whom there exists a natural number $m$ with $n<m$ and $(m,n)=1$ but $(2^m-1,2^n-1)=d>1$

Let $m=kn+a$ with $1<a\leq n-1$.  If $d|2^m-1$ and $d|2^n-1$ then $d|2^a-1$.
If $a=1$ then $d|1$ which means $d=1$ a contradiction.
If $a>1$ then $2^a-1<2^n-1$ has a common divisor with $2^m-1$ which contradicts that $n$ was the smallest proper number for our claim.

Comment: What if $k=0$ and $a=n$ ? Shouldn't be $n=km+a$ and by minimality $k>0$ ?

Comment: if $k=0$ then $m=a$

Comment: There is some confusion. At first $m$ is the smallest number, and in the last sentence, it's $n$.

Comment: @Xoff it needed a small change, see now.

Comment: ok, it's a nice answer :)

Comment: But $n,m$ are arbitrary! Does your answer apply to all $m,n$ ?

Comment: @Mahdi Khosravi arbitrary?No my friend. $m$ seems to be arbitrary but it is not. $n$ is defined in a unique way and  $m$  comes in front because of $n$ -and so neither $n$ nor $m$ are not arbitrary-

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas I mean the only restriction on $m$ and $n$ is that they are relatively prime, nothing else.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi what else do you need?and $n$ is the s m a l l e s t one with the mentioned property(another restriction)

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's algorithm on $(m,n)$ ends with $1$. Apply the map $x\mapsto 2^x-1$ to each of the intermediate values in the algorithm, and you get a way to make $1$ from $2^m-1$ and $2^n-1$ by successively subtracting multiples of one from the other.

If $m \ge an \ge 1$, then
$$2^{m-an}-1 = (2^m-1) - \left(\sum_{j=1}^{a} 2^{m-jn}\right)(2^n-1) $$

In fact, the resulting sequence is exactly what the Euclidean algorithm will produce when started in $(2^m-1,2^n-1)$.